# Populate .net combobox with used range from Excel sheet

Tags: vb.net, excel, combobox

I'm trying to populate a combobox on a Windows Form with the used range from an Excel workbook. The Excel range I need to reference is D32:D62; however, this range is dynamic. It may only contain 5 values, or it may contain 30 depending on what the user inputs into my app. The values in this range will all be offset to the top so there will be no blank cells between values.

```
      'populate ComboBoxProgram with relevant program names for loaded student
    Try

        Dim oRange As Excel.Range
        Dim oRangeArr As String

        oRange = DirectCast(StatVar.xlApp.Sheets("New Calculator Input").UsedRange("D32", "D62"), Excel.Range)
        oRangeArr = String.Empty
        'Build a string array delimited by commas
        For i As Integer = 1 To oRange.Rows.Count
            Dim oCell As Excel.Range = DirectCast(oRange.Rows(i), Excel.Range)
            oRangeArr &= DirectCast(oCell.Value.ToString, String) & ","
        Next

        oRangeArr = oRangeArr.Remove(oRangeArr.Length - 1, 1)
        ComboBoxProgram.Items.AddRange(oRangeArr.Split(","c))
        oRange = Nothing

    Catch exc As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("An error occured while retrieving the relevant programs from the budget. Please contact an administrator for assistance.")
    End Try
```

This will only populate my combobox if all cells in my range have values. How do I find just the used range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel-vbnet) slightly modified approach a shot.  It will check the whole workbook for cells with data and not populate the combobox for empty cells.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
...

Dim excel As Application = New Application

Dim w As Workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\temp\book1.xlsx")
    For i As Integer = 1 To w.Sheets.Count
          Dim sheet As Worksheet = w.Sheets(i)
          Dim r As Range = sheet.UsedRange
          Dim array(,) As Object = r.Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault)
          If array IsNot Nothing Then
              Dim bound0 As Integer = array.GetUpperBound(0)
              Dim bound1 As Integer = array.GetUpperBound(1)

              ' Loop over all elements.
              For j As Integer = 1 To bound0
                  For x As Integer = 1 To bound1
                      Dim s1 As String = array(j, x)
                         If s1 IsNot Nothing Then
                            If Not ComboBox1.Items.Contains(s1.ToString) Then
                                ComboBox1.Items.Add(s1.ToString)
                            End If
                         End If
                  Next
              Next
          End If
     Next
 w.Close()
```

Comment: How do I prevent this from duplicating the items in my combobox? Right now it's duplicating everything multiple times. I need each item to appear only once as it does on my worksheet

Comment: You can add ' If Not combobox1.items.contains(s1.tostring) right before the add() call